# script for simple math fixing input/output size

Tags: perl, math, hex

Looking for an utility or script to do some simple math in hex, decimal or binary (+ - / x) but I want to define the format and size/signal/integer ... of output. For example 0xffff + 1 will have different results if the output goes to an U16 or U32. maybe there is a tool in the web for that or somebody already did something related.

Answer (score 1):

Perl has a bit-wise AND operator (`&`) (see [Bitwise-And in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Bitwise-And)) which can be used to limit an integer to 16 bits.  It also has [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) and [hex](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/hex.html) to perform conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Well perl has a powerful math library Math::BigRat.
see here:
http://perldoc.perl.org/Math/BigRat.html

but for `U16` or `U32` i don't have any idea